# Auto delete elasticsearch data older than 30 days

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have setup a ELK stack to collect logs at central server. It is working perfectly. But by default it is holding elasticsearch index/data permanently. We just want to maintain the data for 30Days. Please anyone point me how to delete indexs/data older than 30 days from elasticsearch DB.
Elasticsearch version is 2.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

There are two easy ways to do this, both require setting up a scheduled task.

1. If you are using time series index names you can do something like

   ```
   curl -DELETE http://es-host:9200/index-yyyy.mm*
   ```
2. If you're not using dates in your index names you will want to use [Elasticsearch Curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator)

Comment: Curator is **designed** for this function, and works pretty well.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins thanks. step one work for me. I have written a script with command.     /usr/bin/curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/index_name/_close"    /usr/bin/curl -XDELETE "http://127.0.0.1:9200/index_name"